What are the differences between the ConcurrentMessageLimit on endpoints and conosumers?
Based on these 1 2 documents, an Endpoint and a Consumer can have a ConcurrentMessageLimit. But how does it affect messages processed on a queue?
I understand an Endpoint can be configured to deliver messages on the same queue to multiple consumers. But I could not figure out a code example to show how it works.
